# How do I change default behaviour of the function keys on a per-application basis?

Tags: macos, system-settings, preferences

I have done a quick search on AskDifferent and I haven't found a precise match for the question I have. I'm relatively new to MacOS and am looking to customise its behaviour. I'm a software developer coming from Windows.

I have Rider installed on MacOS and I want to replicate the Windows experience as much as possible (for this app only).

I have noticed in System Preferences that one can change the default behaviour of the function keys -- i.e. you can choose whether brightness and volume etc. are the default with <kbd>Fn</kbd> needed get <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc., or whether <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc., are the default and <kbd>Fn</kbd> modifier gets to the brightness and volume controls etc..

I would like to have different settings automatically depending on which app has the focus. That is: brightness and volume as default in all other apps, but <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc., being the default in Rider. This means I can do things like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to go straight to class declarations rather than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> which is a bit of a pain.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: A way is using [Karabinier Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) but you will need to use the complex rules

Comment: Fluor https://github.com/Pyroh/Fluor is menubar app which can flip the function keys on a per app basis.  I have not seriously used it, but came across it a while ago.

Comment: Thanks to both commenters above!

I am trying to keep my Mac 'clean' and not install any extensions, but the Fluor one is open source, so I will take a look at that and will probably install.

Thanks again.

Comment: Options depend on hardware as well: (1) whether it has touchbar or not (2) what keyboard is used. For example logi K860 has dedicated key for switching between function and media keys. For automatic switching with touchbar the app must support it.

Comment: Yes indeed -- thanks. I am on a MacBook Air, so I have function keys and no TouchBar.

@Gilby -- once I have built Fluor and explored the extension, I'll write up your suggestion as a proper answer.